# Invalid Header Error Trying to Copy Files From Docker Container

Tags: docker

I am trying to copy files from a running docker container to my local machine.

Local: MacOS 10.15.4 with Docker Desktop 2.2.0.5

My command is:

```
docker cp 361aeca23cd6:/etc/letsencrypt/archive/stage.example.com/fullchain1.pem fullchain1.pem
```

The result is one line of output:

```
gzip: invalid header
```

And nothing is copied.

I have tried all kinds of variations (just copying directories, specifying full destination path, etc.) and the result is always the same.

I know it is finding the source file because if I specify a nonexistent file it returns "No such container path" instead of the above error.

Here is the Dockerfile for the image:

https://github.com/rubyforgood/babywearing/blob/master/docker/web/Dockerfile

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the image that container is running?  Is it a "full" distribution base, built on top of something lighter-weight (Alpine/Busybox), or a "distroless" image that doesn't contain any of the usual Linux tools?  Can you provide a [mcve], including any relevant application source code?

Comment: @david-maze It is based on the nginx image. I edited the question to link to the Dockerfile in the repo. It is deployed to an Azure VM as part of the stack file (one directory up from that Dockerfile).

Comment: @DavidMaze FWIW I get the same behavior trying to copy a file from the app container from https://github.com/rubyforgood/babywearing/blob/master/docker/docker-stack.yml